# Matrix "decomposition" to a difference

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given a matrix:

$$ A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

how can I find a "decomposition" st.
$$ A = B_0 B_0^{\dagger}-B_1 B_1^{\dagger}, $$
where the constraints are: $ Tr(B_{0,1}^{\dagger} \ B_{0,1}) = 1$, $ B_{0,1} \in\mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}$?

This is a specific example, but a general formula for Hermitian matrices $A$ would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**First the general case :**

By the spectral theorem, a Hermitian matrix $A$ is diagonalizable in a orthonormal basis, i.e. there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that :
$$ A = U DU^\dagger \quad \text{with}\quad D= \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 \\&\ddots \\&&\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$$
and the eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)$ are real. By separating positive and negative eigenvalues and taking square roots, we can write  :
$$D = D_0 D_0^\dagger - D_1 D_1^\dagger$$

Then,
\begin{align}
A = (UD_0)(UD_0)^\dagger - (UD_1)(UD_1)^\dagger
\end{align}

which gives $B_i = UD_i$. The equation on the trace is not a constraint. Rather, $\operatorname{Tr}(B_0B_0^\dagger)$ is the sum of the positive eigenvalues of $A$, and $\operatorname{Tr}(B_1B_1^\dagger)$ is the sum of the negative eigenvalues.

**Now the specific example**

Solving the eigenvalue problem, you find that $A = UDU^\dagger$ where :
\begin{align}
U &= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{ 2} & \frac 12& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0\\
 \frac{1}{ 2} & \frac 12& -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}  \end{pmatrix} \\
D &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\&-1 \\&&0\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align}
which gives :
\begin{align}
B_0 &= \begin{pmatrix} \frac 12 &0 & 0 \\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0&0 \\
\frac 12&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
B_1 &= \begin{pmatrix}0& \frac 12& 0 \\0&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\ 0&
\frac 12&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much